# How to determine drive in Windows using Python?

Tags: operating-system, python-3.8, drive

I have string named `C:/`, and I want to detect if this string is path of drive.

Apparently, it seems to be drive, but I want a code or module that determines this is a drive.

I tried `os.path.isdrive` but there was no function like that.

I think answer is very simple one, but I don't know how to do this.

I'm using Python 3.8 and Window. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the path.exists() function:

```
from os import path
path.exists("C:/")
```

If you want to test only for root directory of a drive ("C:/" and not "C:/File/File2/") you could check that by mesuring the lenght of the path:

```
def is_drive(path):
   if len(path) <= 3 and os.path.exists(path):
      return True
   return False
```

This method will return if drive exists. I hope this helps, it really depends on what you want to use this function for.